# How to compile without linking in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to build a small project to create a library of functions I use often.
I am expecting to do only the compiling without linking. So my end output should be a .o file and not an executable.

Any way to change this (I dont want to write a make file ).

At the moment, it is giving the below error since it is using -o and my project does not have a main.

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [util] Error 1
```

Comment: You could create a library project for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1. Create a "library project" via the "New" -> "Project..." wizard. Eclipse CDT will provide a default configuration that instructs the compiler to create an object file instead of an executable.
2. You can change the configuration of your existing project. To do this, right-click on your project, and select "Properties". Then, navigate to "C/C++ Build" -> Settings. Switch to the "Build Artifact"-tab, and change the "Artifact Type" to either "Shared Library" or "Static Library".

Hope this helps.